# Parse a CSV file in AppleScript and selecting columns

Tags: csv, applescript

I am trying to read from a CSV file and compare a variable in AppleScript to the contents of the CSV file. Example of file and variable below.

CSV File:

```
GroupName, DriveLetter, Path
Test1    , E:         , \\networkshare\test1
Test4    , G:         , \\networkshare\test4
```

AppleScript Variable contains:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

If there is a match between the variable and the CSV file (like Test1), I need to select the Path associated with the Test1 line and save it to a new variable, then use that variable to map a volume.

Here is a snippet of the script:

```
    set current_user to system attribute "USER" as text 
    set command to do shell script ("dscl '/Active Directory/DOMAIN/All Domains' -read /Users/" & current_user & " dsAttrTypeNative:memberOf") 
    set group to trim_line(command, "dsAttrTypeNative:memberOf:", 0)
    mount volume "smb://servername/netlogon/"
    set DrivesFile to (read "/volumes/netlogon/drives.csv" using delimiter {",", lf}) 
    repeat with aline in DrivesFile
    if aline is in group then "this is where I need to select the other CSV column and then mount a volume"
    end repeat
```

Comment: Is ´trim_line´ a custom function? What does it return? "Test1" etc? Do I understand correctly that the variable ´group´ contains the data that is labelled "CSV File" in your question? If you look closely at trim_line, you should be able to understand how line and item delimiters work. If nobody is quicker than me, I'll try to post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some stuff in that code that is not necessary for me to show you a solution to your question, so I'll ignore that stuff for now.

This example assumes you read the csv file into applescript as text and you do not use delimiters when reading the file. I'm using "csvtext" to simulate that. I also assume your "group" variable is a list of items.

So given those things here's how I would determine "the other" csv column when your if statement is true. You will need to issue your mount statement where I indicated in the code. Good luck.

```
set csvText to "GroupName, DriveLetter, Path
Test1    , E:         , \\\\networkshare\\test1
Test4    , G:         , \\\\networkshare\\test4"
set group to {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}

set theParagraphs to paragraphs of csvText

set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ", "}
repeat with i from 2 to count of theParagraphs
    set thisParagraph to item i of theParagraphs

    set lineList to text items of thisParagraph
    if word 1 of (item 1 of lineList) is in group then
        set thePath to item 3 of lineList
        -- mount the volume at thePath
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids
```

Comment: regulus6633 - Thank you for your reply and for the great example given above. I had to tweak the repeat function code just a little to get the value that I needed but it is working now.